how to set first row to be the column header in pandas WITHOUT USING ILOC -
[I became informed below in the comments that I misinterpreted the effect of the deprecation for iloc.  I apologize for my misunderstanding. I do not know if I should let this stand or delete the question.  I will try to find outfind out.]
Without beating a dead horse there are all kinds of tips and tricks for setting the first row of a pandas dataframe using iloc (Deprecated since version 2.2.0) - and I always thought that using iloc for that was very pythonic.  Also, there are a variety of other ways to convert the first row to the header row that require multiple steps if you will.
My question is this, without using iloc, is there a simple replacement method that says "grab that first row and make it the header?  (and this is not related to opening a file to create a dataframe, it involves grabbing data out of the middle of a large file and then munging on it)
I can't seem to find one.  And I have googled it to death and looked at a number stackoverflow answers, and even put my search phrases in the stackoverflow search box.  And that search came back with no answer or suggestion other than referring to answers that do use iloc.  I'm out of ideas.

provide [mre] & your desired output

Also, pandas 2.2.0: Returning a tuple from a callable with iloc is deprecated.

iloc is not deprecated, only the specific feature mentioned above. df = df.rename(columns = df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True) works fine - what is the problem?
